# What really is a 'space' and how is it related to 'topology'?

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

so what really is the meaning of a metric space and why is it so important in topology?

Comment: "Also most books on topology speak of metric spaces" Do you have a book like that at your disposal? If it is on introductary level then you will find there what a topology and a metric space is, and how they are related.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of a mathematical space is that it is a set endowed with some type of structure (and the word structure just means there's more to the definition of the set than just a collection of elements -- there's an additional feature added to the set; we call this feature the structure of the set).  Here are some examples to help you get a feel for it:

1. **Metric space**: This is a set $X$ of elements which we endow with a distance function $d: X \times X \to [0,\infty)$.  You input two points $x$ and $y$ from $X$ into the distance function and the output $d(x,y)$, which is a number, we interpret as the distance between $x$ and $y$.  Different metric functions give different notions/interpretations of distance, but they all satisfy three important properties which allow us to call them *distance* functions (i.e., metrics).  So the structure here is the idea of distance between two points.
2. **Topological space**: This is a set $X$ of elements which we endow with a *topology*, i.e., a collection of subsets which we call *open*.  We can endow $X$ with different topologies to give us different ideas of what constitutes an open set, and under these different topologies we can examine if functions between topological spaces are open, and if sequences in a topological space converge.  You can have different topologies, but all topologies must satisfy three important properties which allow us to call them topologies.  So the structure here is a collection of subsets of $X$ which we call open.
3. **Group**: In Abstract Algebra, a group is a set $X$ of elements which we endow with a certain property (call it multiplication but it's not the same as ordinary number multiplication -- it's more general).  Under this multiplication, the set now has structure because we can look at how two elements interact with each other under multiplication.  If the elements in the set behave in such a way that they satisfy some important properties, we call the set a *group*.  So the structure here is an operation between two elements called multiplication, and from here you can see how elements interact with each other under this operation.  A group can be thought of as a space.

Comment: As an addition to my answer above: the reason books link metric spaces and topological spaces is that every metric space can be thought of as a topological space (but not vice versa -- not every topological space can be endowed with a metric).  So the idea of distance that a metric gives will give us an idea of open sets, from which we can define a topology.  So out of a metric space arises a topological space (but you can have topological spaces that **don't** arise from a metric space).

Answer (score 1):

There is no single mathematical idea of "space".

Each different kind of space --- vector space; metric space; topological space --- is studied in a different course of mathematics. Googling is not going to get you to a good understanding of all of these different kinds of spaces. You'll have to do some serious studying.

For example, to study vector spaces, take a course (or read a book) on linear algebra; there are a zillion such books.

To study metric spaces, take a course, or read a book, on metric spaces. There are a few good books devoted to metric spaces. I like [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521318971), and there are other good ones. Metric spaces are also studied in any topology book.

To study topological spaces, take a course, or read a book, on topology.